# Getting 400 bad request

Tags: jquery, python, html, ajax, flask

I am writing the following HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/grafana_style_sheet.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#Click").click(function(){
            alert('hi '+ $('#databases').val());
            var data1 = new Object();

            data1.name = $('#databases').val();
            data1.dbname = 'grafana';

            alert(data1.dbname + " " + data1.name);
            $.ajax({
                url : "dashboards",
                type : 'POST',
                data : 'data1',
                dataType : "text",
                success : function(){
                    data = JSON.parse(data);
                    console.log("hi " + data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">Report Suites</div>
    <form>
        <fieldset id = "fieldset">
            <legend align = "center"><font color= "#00008B"><strong>Select your Report Suite<strong></font></legend>
            <select id ="databases" name = "db">
                <option value = "">--Select From following--</option>
                <option value = "HARMONY">HARMONY</opton>
                <option value = "CAMPS">CAMPS</opton>
                <option value = "QBSU">QBSU</opton>
                <option value = "SIMBA">SIMBA</opton>
            </select>
            <br><br>
            <button type = "button" id = "Click"> Click Me!!</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

            <div id ="placeholder"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

To run the above HTML code, i wrote the following Python programme using Flask so as to send data from the form (above) and run a query based on it.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, json, request
from flask import Flask, request, abort, jsonify
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
import MySQLdb

app = Flask(__name__)

def connection(database):
    db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","",database)
    cursor = db.cursor()
    return cursor

@app.route("/")
def main():
    return render_template('grafana_try1.html')

@app.route("/dashboards",methods=['POST'])
def connect():  
    dtb = request.form['dbname']
    b = request.form['name']
    conn = connection(dtb)

    conn.execute("SELECT * FROM SuiteDetails WHERE RS_name=%s",b)
    results = conn.fetchall()
    json_return_value =[]

    for result in results:
        table_data = {'RS_name' : result[0], 'RS_id' : result[1], 'Staging_db' : result[2], 'Trans_db' : result[3], 'Base_Date' : result[4], 'graph_link' : result[5]}
        json_return_value.append(table_data)
    print json.dumps(json_return_value)
    return json.dumps(json_return_value)  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

When i run it on firefox , I get 400 BAD REQUEST response.

Please tell me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you check the request that is made in the "network" section of your browser dev tools?

Comment: i am running it on firefox and using firebug. It gave some Request Headers as follows:Accept 
text/plain, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding 
gzip, deflate
Accept-Language 
en-US,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control 
no-cache
Connection 
keep-alive
Content-Length 
5
Content-Type 
application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host 
127.0.0.1:5000
Pragma 
no-cache
Referer 
http://127.0.0.1:5000/
User-Agent 
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
X-Requested-With 
XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Is this that you wanted

Comment: What's the "Request URL"? (you can click in a request and copy it from Headers Tab)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the Problem is in the jQuery POST, you're not passing the full url, just the action and you want to pass `data1` instead of `'data1'` (you want the object, not the string). So instead of:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "dashboards",
    type : 'POST',
    data : 'data1',
    dataType : "text",
    success : function(){
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log("hi " + data);
    }
});
```

You should have:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "http://<YOUR_HOST>/dashboards",
    type : 'POST',
    data : data1,
    dataType : "text",
    success : function(){
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log("hi " + data);
    }
});
```

Note that you should change `<YOUR_HOST>` by your host, if you're runnning it locally (and with flask defaulst) it should be `127.0.0.1:5000`.

Hope this helps

Comment: I found the error. I should pass data : data1 rather than data : 'data1'. data1 is my object and by enclosing it within quotes, i am sending it as a string. I removed the quotes and my code is working good. Thanks for the quick response :)

Comment: Right, missed that too, I always use the full Uri, but maybe because you're in the root of the same domain that works too.Going to edit my answer to include that too.